# PPTP соединение перекрывает инет трафик

Tags: lan, nat

Доброго времени суток!

Товарищи, есть nat, который раздает маршрутизатор и есть vpn (pptp) подключение. При установке подключения к vpn инет обрубается, те трафик идет только по защищенному каналу.

Имеем 2 сети:

```
11.2.11.1(vpn) и 192.168.1.1
```

Нужно, что бы можно было ходить в инет из без выключения vpn соединения. Делал так

```
route add 11.2.11.0 mask 255.255.0.0 192.168.1.1 ok
```

далее маршрут добавляется, но все ровно инет трафик не идет. Подскажите, добрые люди, куда копать?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш ВПН при подключении устанавливает маршрут (шлюз) по-умолчанию (default gateway).

Отключите данную опцию, для этого поищите в тырнете, как сие делается, полагаю, что у вас Windows 7. Если так, открываете:

1. "Свойства" ВПН соединения
2. Вкладка "Сеть"
3. "Протокол интернета версии 4..." свойства
4. Кнопка "Дополнительно..."
5. Убираете галку "Использовать основной шлюз..."

В таком случае делается наоборот, в сеть вы выходить будете с помощью NAT, а для выхода в сеть ВПН вам придется прописывать маршруты.

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек попробуем)))))))))))